# Can composer packages require each other?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two local packages:

- "myrep/package1": "dev-master"
- "myrep/package2": "dev-master"

they require each other. When I run `composer update` on one of them composer says:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for myrep/package1 dev-master -> satisfiable by myrep/package2[dev-master].
    - myrep/package1 dev-master requires myrep/package2 dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

but both `composer.json` files contain `"minimum-stability": "dev"`.

I need my packages to require each other, how can I overcome this problem ?
Is this situation allowed by composer ?

Comment: No, you can't. It creates a circular references that will never be resolved.

Comment: If two packages require each other to work correctly, it doesn't make a lot of sence to split them. Combine them to one package instead.